# Studying "co-authorship" in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, legal, research

I am considering investigating the "co-authorship" network on Stack Overflow.  This would involve things like generating a network based on who gives answers to the same questions, or possibly who asks questions that are frequently answered by a particular individual.

Before I do this, I want to make sure that I'm not reproducing something that someone else has done and that I'm not violating any terms.  I don't see anything here: https://stackexchange.com/legal that looks like a problem, but I'm relatively new to Stack Overflow, so there may be nuances I don't understand.

Would there be any reason I should refrain from collecting the "co-authorship" data and publishing results in an academic journal?

Comment: It seems strange that this never got any responses.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Agreed - though given my current institution, it's no longer something that fits into my research plans.